# Potential Energy and its definitions

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, potential-energy

In the definition of potential energy the final part in the definition seems a bit unclear for me, it says; "Potential energy of a system depends upon the **virtue of the positions of the particles with respect to each other** in the system"

To me it feels like we analyzed a handful of conservative forces and realized that these conservative forces depends on the position of the particles wrt each other. Is there a way to confirm this that this statement is true for any conservative force that we can have?